# Angular jsonp callback executing only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

**config**

```
(function() {

  angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

  angular.module('plunker').config(['$routeProvider', moduleConfig]);

  function moduleConfig($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html', //url of the template
        controller: 'HomeCtrl', //name of the controller
        controllerAs: 'hCtrl' //how it should be referred in the template
      })
      .when('/profile', {
        templateUrl: 'profile.html', //url of the template
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl', //name of the controller
        controllerAs: 'pCtrl' //how it should be referred in the template
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
  }


  //controllers should be in their own .js files
  angular.module('plunker').controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl);
  angular.module('plunker').controller('ProfileCtrl',['myservice', ProfileCtrl]);

  function HomeCtrl() {
    var hCtrl = this;
    alert('HomeCtrl');
  }

  function ProfileCtrl(myservice) {

    var pCtrl = this;
    myservice.retrive(function(data){
      alert('profile');
    });
  }

})();
```

**myservice**

```
(function(){

    angular.module('plunker')
        .factory('myservice',myservice);

    myservice.$inject=['$http'];

    function myservice($http) {

        var factory={
            retrive:retrive
        };

        return factory;

        function retrive(callback){

            var url = 'test.json';
            var params = {
                    callback: 'angular.callbacks._0'
                };

            $http.jsonp(url, {params: params}).then(callback);
        }
    }


})();
```

I wrote this controller and service for a particular page, let say "/profile".  profile controller uses a service which has JSONP request. when I go to that page("/profile") everything works and JSONP callback executes. But when I go to "/index" after "/profile" and come back again to "/profile" JSONP call fires but callback in controller is not executed. can some one spot the error

plnkr with code http://plnkr.co/edit/fswywkpsH6xl5XU0YplK?p=preview

In this plnkr the callback in profile controller executes only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is angular will internally increment the jsonp callback value as a tracking mechanism

You must use the documented query string `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK`.

The value `JSON_CALLBACK` is just a placeholder that `$http` will replace internally with values like:

```
angular.callbacks._0
angular.callbacks._1
angular.callbacks._2
```

The problem with your implementation is you always return `angular.callbacks._0()` so the next call that expects `angular.callbacks._1()` isn't receiving that value and will thus reject the request

Change your service method to:

```
  function retrive(callback){

        var url = 'test.json';
        var params = {
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            };

        $http.jsonp(url, {params: params}).then(callback ).catch(function(err){
          console.log(err)
        });
    }
```

And in your demo you will see that `err.status` is `404` on the second request

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/jAu2R6D9ZbP5sCF0YWr4?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: can you tell me why it fails? Is there a way to get the callback working?

Comment: sure, your api should just wrap the json in the dynamic `callback` param that is sent. For example in php .. `echo $_GET['callback'] .'(' . $json . ')';`

Comment: I am trying to hit yelp api. it seems yelp doen't support this

Comment: does it support jsonp? Not all API's do support it

Answer (score 1):

It's executing twice but failing the second time with a 404. You can see the failure if you add the error handler function:

```
$http.jsonp(url, {params: params}).then(callback, function() { console.log('I\'ve failed you:', arguments); })
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this modification: http://plnkr.co/edit/5HnXfpjZEzVhtCUjonGa?p=preview

You can add a flag `dataLoaded` in `myservice` that is changed from `false` to `true` when data is retrieved first time, and the check it in the controller:

```
//in controller code    
if(!myservice.dataLoaded) {
   myservice.retrive(function(data){
     myservice.dataLoaded = true;
     alert('profile');
   });
 }

//in service code
var factory={
  retrive:retrive,
  dataLoaded: false
};
```

Comment: There is nothing change in plnkr behavior. profile alert did not come for the second time

Comment: so you need 'myservice.retrive(function(data){' to fire EVERY time you get to /profile ?

Comment: exactly. i need callback which sets the retrieved data to model